# Does the base act as a repair beacon?

Tags: ftl-faster-than-light

I'm at The Last Stand and about to make a strategic decision - either hit one extra beacon, get some more scrap but probably take some damage, or go straight to the Base and fight the flagship. What I do depends on the answer to this question:

**Do you get free repairs when you get to the base?**

I can't remember whether or not you do from previous playthroughs, and can't find any info online.

Comment: I'm pretty sure it does nothing

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The base in *The Final Stand* sector does not repair your ship or offer you resources of any kind. It is always a 'naked' beacon.

From the FTL wiki on [The Rebel Flagship](http://ftl.wikia.com/wiki/The_Rebel_Flagship) page:

> The base gives you no repair, and is the primary target of the Rebel Flagship.

In my headcanon, the Federation base is the base of political power and has no military resources to offer.

Comment: I'l take your word for it. If I ever have an opportunity to double check I'll come back and leave a comment to corroborate.